# How to add to a list multiple selected values of a ListBox ? C#, ASP.NET web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I'm working on one of my first projects. I have a listbox where I select multiple values and I would like to add each selection (selectedItem.Text) to a list of strings.

so far what I was working on is something like ..

```
selectedItem = new List<string>();
 var value = lstpdfList.SelectedItem.Text;
 for (int i = 0; i < lstpdfList.SelectedValue.Count(); i++)
 {
  selectedItem.Add(value);
 }
```

I would really appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate each item from ListBox.Items collection

```
foreach (ListItem  item in ListBox1.Items)
 {
  if (item.Selected)
  {
    selectedItem.Add(item.Text); // selectedImte.Add(item.Value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Somehow my VS 2010 doesn't recognize listbox.selectedItems. SelectedItem works.

Answer (score 0):

There is [SelectedItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditems%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property of ListBox, try to iterate throught it. For example, if there is strings in your ListBox, then your code might look like this:

```
selectedItem = new List<string>();
foreach (string value in lstpdfList.SelectedValues)
  selectedItem.Add(value);
```

Comment: Edited my question. is ASP.NET web site in C#, can't call SelectedItems just SelectedItem

Answer (score 0):

You can just cast them to strings:

```
var selectedItems = listBox1.SelectedItems
    .Cast<string>()
    .ToList();
```

If you have populated your ListBox with something other than just strings, just cast to whichever type you need, like so:

```
var selectedItems = listBox1.SelectedItems
    .Cast<WhateverYourTypeIs>()
    .Select(item => item.ToString())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Edited my question. is ASP.NET web site in C#, can't call SelectedItems just SelectedItem